# Bridge handler can't access stash data

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I have the following code in our webapp written using Mojolicious, and it doesn't work as expected: the bridge handler doesn't get the correct stash data derived from routes (gets undef), so the rest of code fails, however, debug output of $self->stash('city') in any of route handlers is as expected.

---

```
...
# Router.
my $r = $self->routes->bridge->to('Main#common');
$r->route('/')->to('Main#index')->name('start');
$r->route('/:region/:city/category/:id')->to('Main#list_category')->name('list_category');
$r->route('/:region/:city/part/:id/:name')->to('Main#show_part')->name('show_part');
...
# Controller.
sub common
{
    my $self=shift;
    my $db=$self->db;
    my $city=$self->stash('city');
    my $region=$self->db->selectrow_hashref('select * from region where LOWER(translit)=? ORDER BY region_id LIMIT 1',undef,$city);
    say "City=$city.";
    if(!$region)
    {
        $region={};
    }
    $self->stash(region=>$region);
    return 1;
}
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's correct behavior.
Look at [this](https://metacpan.org/source/SRI/Mojolicious-6.45/lib/Mojolicious/Routes.pm#L31) code. 
Placeholder is added when the appropriate route is taken to the processing, i.e., step by step.

Really, look at you routes.

```perl
my $r = $self->routes->bridge->to('Main#common');
$r->route('/')->to('Main#index')->name('start');
$r->route('/:region/:city/category/:id')->to('Main#list_category')->name('list_category');
$r->route('/:region/:city/part/:id/:name')->to('Main#show_part')->name('show_part');
```

I can't understand what behavior you expect when go to route /.
Sub `common` will be invoked in this case. There are no value for placeholder `city`!

So, correct solution for your routes must look like this:

```
my $r = $self->routes;
$r->route('/')->to('Main#index')->name('start');

my $r_city = $r->bridge('/:region/:city/')->to('Main#common');
$r_city->route('/category/:id')->to('Main#list_category')->name('list_category');
$r_city->route('/part/:id/:name')->to('Main#show_part')->name('show_part');
```

By the way,

starting from Mojolicious version 6.0 `bridge` was deprecated to favor `under`. So, you need to replace `bridge` on `under`.

But, if you very-very want to have value of placeholder `city` in `common` function, you may look at [this](https://metacpan.org/source/SRI/Mojolicious-6.45/lib/Mojolicious/Routes.pm#L23-24) two line.
You need to write this **BAD** code in `common` sub:

```
sub common {
  my $self = shift;
  my $stack = $self->match->stack;
  warn $self->dumper($stack);
  ...
}
```

Print `$stack` and you understand how to get value of placeholder `city`.

Comment: The code under the bridge is needed in all requests.

Comment: For route / is pointless. I showed in the code and explained that the way you want it will not work because is pointless. But i add solution with $self->match->stack which explain how to get this value if you very very want it.